"Collect all and save" saving unnecessary samples
I'm trying to collaborate with a friend on an Ableton project. I shared the project with them over Google Drive, and some of the samples were missing. To correct this, I opened the project and chose File > Collect all and save to save all the samples within the project folder.
However, Ableton now seems to have copied over way too many samples into the project folder. There are only three recorded samples used in the current version of the .als set, but the Samples > Recorded folder now contains 329 files (at 6+ GB). Perhaps some of these are from previous takes, but I'm no longer using those takes. I often duplicate a template .als file that has my default settings in it, so perhaps these takes were used in previous iterations of that template.
Any advice? Am I misunderstanding how Collect all and save works? Are there other steps I can take to prune the sample files down to only what's currently used in the set?

For details, see: https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209775645-Collect-All-and-Save
There is more granularity available for the "Collect all and save" function and it is also possible to see what files will or would be collected.
You can access these more granular options via:
File → Manage Files → Manage Project → External Files → Collect Into Project

The dialog pictured has buttons to show the files that will be collected from two different categories: files from the User Library and files from Factory Packs. You can use these buttons to figure how what these extra files are. It's worth noting that if you have any sample-based instruments that come from Factory Packs, all of the samples for every note and articulation may be collected with the project.
This forum post suggests you can clean up old takes and associated audio files by deleting unused take lanes. You can also try going to:
File → Manage Files → Manage Set → View Files
